# How to automate Windows Update with PowerShell?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-update, windows-task-scheduler

***Why I want to do this***:

When Windows Update ran without warning, hogged resources and rendered my computer nearly unusable for a long time,

I had used:

```
 net stop wuauserv
 wmic service where name="TrustedInstaller" call stopservice
 taskkill /f /im TiWorker.exe
```

And met serious consequence(update failed and kept being installed upon (re)boot and kept being rolled back), however it is important to keep my computer up to date for security.

***What I want to achieve***

Schedule a time to automatically scan, download and install updates and prevent unscheduled auto-update, only install updates while I am not using my computer, so that it will not slow down my PC.

***What I had tried***

cmd:

```
Reg Add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\TrustedInstaller /v Start /t REG_dword /d 3 /f
Reg Add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\UsoSvc /v Start /t REG_dword /d 3 /f
Reg Add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WaaSMedicSvc /v Start /t REG_dword /d 3 /f
Reg Add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv /v Start /t REG_dword /d 3 /f
```

I can confirm these settings won't achieve my intended result.

gpedit.msc "Local Computer Policy"->"Computer Configuration"->"Administrative Templates"->"Windows Components"->"Windows Update"->"Configure Automatic Updates"

I had configured it to this:

[image]

(At 00:00 every Sunday on fourth week of every month)

And the effect:

[image]

If not all updates are restricted to the schedule, then it means nothing;

I know I can pause Windows Update but I doing it manually would be tiresome, though pausing Windows Update is useful. I am able to use taskschd to create scheduled tasks for script files, I want to programmatically pause Windows Update and schedule automatic update.

Update:

I have managed these with the help of @TOOGAM, using info from this link:

https://erdentec.com/pausing-windows-10-updates-indefinitely/

What I achieved:

```
$PauseStart=(Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")
$PauseEnd=(Get-Date).AddMonths(1).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate\UX\Settings" -Name "PauseFeatureUpdatesEndTime" -Type "String" -Value $PauseEnd
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate\UX\Settings" -Name "PauseQualityUpdatesEndTime" -Type "String" -Value $PauseEnd
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate\UX\Settings" -Name "PauseUpdatesExpiryTime" -Type "String" -Value $PauseEnd
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate\UX\Settings" -Name "PauseFeatureUpdatesStartTime" -Type "String" -Value $PauseStart
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate\UX\Settings" -Name "PauseQualityUpdatesStartTime" -Type "String" -Value $PauseStart
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU" -Name "AUOptions" -Type "DWord" -Value 2
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU" -Name "NoAutoUpdate" -Type "DWord" -Value 1
Start-Service -Name "Wuauserv"
```

However I can't let it automatically install updates, I had run this:

```
Get-Command -Module *Update*

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Function        Get-WindowsUpdateLog                               1.0.0.0    WindowsUpdate
Function        Get-WUAVersion                                     1.0.0.2    WindowsUpdateProvider
Function        Get-WUIsPendingReboot                              1.0.0.2    WindowsUpdateProvider
Function        Get-WULastInstallationDate                         1.0.0.2    WindowsUpdateProvider
Function        Get-WULastScanSuccessDate                          1.0.0.2    WindowsUpdateProvider
Function        Install-WUUpdates                                  1.0.0.2    WindowsUpdateProvider
Function        Start-WUScan                                       1.0.0.2    WindowsUpdateProvider
```

I had run this and encountered an error:

```
Start-WUScan
Invoke-CimMethod: C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\WindowsUpdateProvider\MSFT_WUOperations.psm1:13
Line |
  13 |  …  $scanres = Invoke-CimMethod -Namespace root/Microsoft/Windows/Window …
     |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Provider load failure

Start-WUScan: Scan hit error: .ReturnValue
```

Also I am unable to make PowerShell manage scheduled tasks located in \Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate in taskschd(although I can use schtasks in cmd and I know I can use cmd commands in pwsh but I want to do this in pure PowerShell spirit...)

I am able to use taskschd and I can create a scheduled task to run .ps1 files(just put "C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" into program/script and use -file path\to\ps1 as argument)

How can I solve the problems that are in my way?

Update:

I had installed the Module: PSWindowsUpdate

```
Set-PSRepository -Name "PSGallery" -InstallationPolicy Trusted
Install-Module -Name PSWindowsUpdate
```

Had run this and here is the result:

```
Get-WindowsUpdate

ComputerName Status     KB          Size Title
------------ ------     --          ---- -----
UTILCOM-466… -------    KB4577194  607MB SQL Server 2019 RTM Cumulative Update (CU) 8 KB4577194
UTILCOM-466… -D-----    KB4592438  103GB 2020-12 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 20H2 for x64-based Systems (…
```

Notice the size of KB4592438... It's 103GB...

Have a look at this:

https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4592438

[image]

What on earth is wrong?

I had put together this:

```
if ("PSWindowsUpdate" -notin (Get-Module -ListAvailable).name) {Set-PSRepository -Name "PSGallery" -InstallationPolicy Trusted;Install-Module -Name PSWindowsUpdate}
```

I know I can use:

```
Get-WindowsUpdate
Install-WindowsUpdate
```

Theoretically it will work, but look at the size of KB4592438 shown by Get-WindowsUpdate...

***Disclaimer***:

I ***Know*** I can use this cmd one-liner to automatically scan, download and install Windows Update, but that isn't PowerShell and this is strictly against pure PowerShell spirit, I had ***explicitly*** stated that I intend to use "PowerShell Core 7" and "Task Scheduler" to achieve this and only using them, not cmd, which in my view isn't professional enough:

```
wuauclt /detectnow /updatenow
```

Comment: Personally, I just paused the updates until the year 9999 using a modification of information at https://erdentec.com/pausing-windows-10-updates-indefinitely/

Comment: @TOOGAM I had accessed the address you gave me, and that is exactly the information I was looking for, thanks, I can create a powershell script from it...

Comment: This PowerShell Module could also be interesting for you. https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSWindowsUpdate/2.2.0.2

Comment: Please will someone migrate this question to stackoverflow? I think it's a specific programming thing.

Comment: What are you having a problem with here Alien, anything at all still? Also, for Windows 10 use `usoclient /startinteractivescan`. Is the issue really issues automating Windows 10 still or are you thinking something is earthly corrupt per the misjudged size of `103GB` for the cumulative update? The key to triggering the Windows Updates when you want it to also set the Active Hours and use the correlated `usoclient` commands either invoked remotely or on the machine itself at the times you need it to run, etc. @XeнεiΞэnвϵς

Comment: @XeнεiΞэnвϵς ... On one of my earth bases I manage hundreds of Windows 10 OSes and Server OSes using a combination of WSUS, group policy and group policy preferences (to set the specific registry values as you do with the PS commands), and running `usoclient` commands. When I approve in WSUS I ensure those machines on on the network or WOL to make as such and then on scheduler running the various `usoclient` commands invoked and such. It works well and makes managing updates to hundreds of servers and workstations streamlined and simplified. I don't think this is a programming question.

Comment: I don't understand your worldly E.T. language we here on Earth call "Silence" and not the type of the Lambs! If you wanna talk some Goo Goo Gaa Gaa though, I understand baby talk but the silence is too cryptic for me to decipher. Do you have a Gmail address?

Comment: Hmm.. About not updating this question, I am currently working on my big project to reduce Windows 10 to bare-bones, so I will not be very active for a while...

Comment: No worries, potentially helpful tips if applicable in your environment for Windows 10 smaller footprints: **1.** [`Compact.exe /CompactOS:always`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/compact-os) and **2.** Google about `DelProf2.exe` and using auto login which works great keeping profiles under control **3.** see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28852786/automate-process-of-disk-cleanup-cleanmgr-exe-without-user-intervention/64106041#64106041 and incorporate `dism` cleanup commands into it as well **4.** I've read about "Windows 10 Lean" but never tried it.

Comment: I want to see your solution if you decide to add a self-question and self-answer with it. Tag me back if so. I has VMware Windows 10 images at 31 GB "C" drives or that I keep around 15 GB used as shown here: https://i.imgur.com/23KakrE.png and running those stackexchange post commands with dism commands, I am also able to update those no problem to newest feature updates without issue. I'm just a sysadmin but hit me up and let me know how it goes.