# automatically update Microsoft Defender Antivirus defentions - Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, anti-virus, windows-defender

**tl;dr** I would like Windows Update to automatically download and install ***only*** the updates "*Security Intelligence Update for Microsoft Defender Antivirus*".

Currently, Windows Update policy is *Download the updates automatically an notify me when they are ready to be installed*. However, I'd like an exception for the Microsoft Defender Antivirus. The Virus Definition updates are near-daily. I don't want to be bothered with several clicks to install them, and there is no reason to delay this install.

How can I set *Windows Update* to automatically install the updated virus definitions, "*Security Intelligence Update for Microsoft Defender Antivirus*", but not automatically install other updates?

Comment: There is [a similar question here](https://superuser.com/questions/117616/automatic-windows-defender-updates-with-manual-windows-microsoft-updates) but it was asked in 2010 and regards Windows 7. Not relevant to my question.

Comment: WD does not notify of updates on any computer here - 10 or 11.  Try this:  https://www.pcworld.com/article/3120305/how-to-turn-off-windows-defenders-enhanced-notifications-in-windows-10.html

Comment: Unfortunately, Windows Update settings are global, and thus apply to all updates. So you would have to download the signatures manually yourself. [MpCmdRun.exe -SignatureUpdate](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/command-line-utility-for-microsoft-security-essentials) still works on all supported versions of Windows 10.

Comment: Another similar question [How to automate Windows Update with PowerShell?](https://superuser.com/questions/1613729/how-to-automate-windows-update-with-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

There's simply no way to achieve the stated goal of the question via Windows Update config, as Windows Updates in Windows 10 doesn't have this option. However, an alternativ is to create a scheduled task to run a manual Definition Update for Windows Defender, which you can schedule to run daily (or whatever you like).
This allows you to set whatever Windows Update settings you prefer for all of your Windows Updates - while still getting regular Windows Defender antivirus definition updates applied automatically without any user input.

Here's a basic rundown of the steps required:

1. Open Task Sheduler

   - Right click on Task Scheduler Library, select -> Create New Basic
     Task
   - Give the task a name (eg 'Automatic Daily Windows Defender Updates'), and click the Next button
   - Leave the Trigger setting to Daily (adjust as needed), and click Next
   - Leave the Daily setting to 'Recur every 1 days' (adjust as needed), and click Next
   - Leave the Action on 'Start a program', and click Next
   - In the Program/Script field enter: "C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MpCmdRun.exe" (the quotes ARE required)
   - In the Add Arguments field enter: '-SignatureUpdate' (NO quotes), and click Next
   - Click on Finish button to complete the task
   - Double click on the new task you've created and select from the General tab, select 'Run whether user is logged in or not', click OK, and enter the password for your account (use an administrative account if your user account is not a member of the Administrators group)
2. Optionally, verify its working:

   - You can run the task now and then check that it gets an exit code of '0' (zero) which means it's succeeded downloading and installing the updates, or checking and found no newer updates.
   - If your Windows Update section/tab in PC Settings is still showing a 'Security Intelligence Update for Microsoft Defender Antivirus' as available to download/install, then its just because it hasn't refreshed its list:

     - Open a command prompt as administrator, enter "UsoClient.exe StartScan" (no quotes) and hit enter to run a check of any new updates manually (will run based on your configured Windows Update settings)
     - Wait a couple of minutes, then re-open the Windows Update section of PC Settings again, and it should show no pending Security Intelligence Updates

Reference: https://www.urtech.ca/2014/08/solved-how-to-make-windows-defender-to-update-automatically/